# Help me choose an external (USB 3.0) hdd

Tags: usb, hard-disk, data-storage

I need an external 4TB hdd with usb 3.0 connection. I need it for using as a storage for my (local network) *media server* and for *regular backups*. I want to buy a *silent, reliable and longevous disk*, its speed is not the most important point. But, if possible, i'd like to have around 100/100MBytes per second read/write speed.

My variants are listed [here (imgur pick)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN3Ha.png):

- Seagate STDR4000200,
- Seagate STEA4000400 and
- Western Digital My Passport 4 TB (WDBUAX0040B)

are 2.5" usb-powered HDD's;

- Seagate STEB4000200 and
- Western Digital WD Elements Desktop 4 TB (WDBWLG0040HBK-EESN)

are 3.5" HDD's with external power supply.

Of course, I would prefer 2.5" size, if these HDD's aren't worse than their big analogs. Besides, I think that not soldered usb port have not of the last importance. Finally, I do not trust Seagate very much, because I had some unfortunate experience with their products, but this can only be a biased opinion.

Comment: You may want to note that Seagate HDDs have kind of a bad reputation these days as can be seen in BackBlaze's quarterly reports ([2017Q2](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/hard-drive-failure-stats-q2-2017/)).

Comment: If you look through the history of BackBlaze's reports, you'll see that the Seagate 3TB and 4TB drives in particular have annual failure rates upwards of 30%.